# How can I increase the longevity of my bananas?

Tags: storage-lifetime, fresh, bananas, ripe

I have some bananas that I just bought at Trader Joe's.  They're nice, fresh, yellow, and full of general banana-ness.  But if I take more than a week or so to eat them all, they start to get brown and less appetizing.  **Is there a way I can increase the shelf life of my bananas by a few days or so?**

Comment: According to my grandfather they were not even ripe until they were black all over. ;^)

Answer (score 0):

My wife freezes bananas since we buy so many for our two year old and they always taste perfect even after weeks. The peel practically gets frozen and prevents any freezer burn flavor!